# I want to link a radio button with a php file

Tags: php, html, button, radio-button, action

I want to link when the user choose one of the radio button below to one of the php files, also I put a button and this button doesn't appear I don't know why  :

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="">
<h4><b>Please choose one of the following options below : </b> </h4>
<input type="radio" name="option" value="search" /> Search <br/>
<input type="radio" name="option" value="open database" /> Open Database<br/>
<input type="radio" name="option" value="administrative page "/> Administrative Page <br/>
</form>
// This button doesn't appear in the web page =( .. dunno why 
<form action="">
<input type="button" value="Choose ">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your users have no way of submitting your form?

Comment: by clicking the choose button but it does't appear in my website, I dunno why ?

Comment: You need to reformat you HTML and include only one form element.  The "Choose" button should really be an input type="submit" button with a value="Choose".

Comment: Yes I did, I understand my fault .. Thanks for ur comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make your code like this

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="">
<h4><b>Please choose one of the following options below : </b> </h4>
<input type="radio" name="option" value="search" /> Search <br/>
<input type="radio" name="option" value="open database" /> Open Database<br/>
<input type="radio" name="option" value="administrative page "/> Administrative Page <br/>
<input type="submit" value="Choose ">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that the button is in the same `<form>` tag as the radio options and that it is a `submit` input type instead of a `button`

You can see the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/Sv6q2/

Here an example without button, but with onclick event on the radio's (note you don't need a `<form>` tag anymore):

```
<html>
<body>
<h4><b>Please choose one of the following options below : </b> </h4>
<input type="radio" name="option" value="search" onclick="document.location.href='search.php'"/> Search <br/>
<input type="radio" name="option" value="open database" onclick="document.location.href='database.php'" /> Open Database<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="administrative page " onclick="document.location.href='admin.php'"/> Administrative Page <br/>
</body>
</html>​
```

And the result you can find here: http://jsfiddle.net/Sv6q2/2/

Comment: So there is no way to choose and click one of the radio button and it will transfer me to the appropriate php page without putting the "Choose " button.. Also from where I have to put the code that will transfer me to a specific php page when I choose one of the above radio button ??

Comment: of course there is, but that is not exactly what you asked, you can add an onclick event on the radio button

Comment: At this format the code will be ..                               <input type="radio" name="option" value="search" /> Search onclick="window.location.href='option_Frame.php'" />

Comment: yes, I tried it and it works but when I put it in my notepadd ++ and save then try it in a website it doesn't work .. really I duuno why

Comment: can you post a link to your website?

Comment: Should I put my IP address and then the name of my php file .. ? Sorry for asking u too many question but really ur comment is very helpful . .

Comment: you can try to change `onclick="document.location.href='search.php'"/>` to `onclick="document.location.href='http://127.0.0.1/site/search.php'"/>` of course you have to put the right URL for your site

Comment: I know now my mistake .. it was a wrong in the spelling of my file .. I appreciate your help .. Thanks a lot ..

Answer (score 0):

You should use jquery. Without it it's hard.

First write a little function that handles click operation, than call your function via

```
onChance="myFunction(this);"
```

Also add a custom attribute to your radio buttons that includes you php file names you want to go.